# Can't activate and deactivate plugins

Tags: plugins

I am trying to activate a plugin. It says as if the plugin is activated but when I am trying to open the plugin's settings page it's says I don't have privileges. When I activate a plugin and then refresh the plugins page, it's as if I did nothing, the plugin isn't active.

It's the same when trying to deactivate a plugin. It looks like the plugin is deactivated but when refreshing the plugins page, it's still active.

It doesn't matter what plugin. It's happening with every plugin.

Does anyone know why is it and have a solution?

Comment: What user "role" does your user have?

Answer (score 1):

**First always take a full backup of your site and database before doing anything.**

Via FTP rename your Plugins folder to "Plugins_bak" and make another Plugins folder.

Then go to WordPress dashboard try installing any plugin and see if you can activate - deactivate them.

If this works then there must be an issue with one of your plugins.